# Integrating swagger api to Java application

Tags: java, rest, swagger

I've been googling for some time on how to use Swagger in Java application but I did not find any helpful resources so I'm asking here. I know it's quite general question but I need to find some kind of starting point to be able to get next steps.

So, I have JavaEE application which gets some JSON through http, parses it and does sth with this data. I was given a totally new API specification made in Swagger (1.2 to be exact). The problem is that I do not know how to stick it together with my application.

1. Should I load JSON file with spec to my application and then do sth with it?
2. Should I use swagger-codegen to generate Java client code and then use it someway in my application?

And what is the 3rd step? How to invoke http requests with this Swagger api?
In general, the question is about integrating Swagger json api to Java application. I would be very grateful for any hints or links to tutorial or sth:)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've the API specification in Swagger (1.2), you can use Swagger Codegen to generate the Java API client and use it in your JavaEE application.

Here is one way to generate the Java API client online without installing swagger-codegen locally:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#online-generators